# jquery addclass() removeclass() on/off selected/clicked

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

So for the past couple weeks I've been struggling to get this code right. I have a clothing website with a standard product page. On this product page I have option images (blue label has blue image, red label has red image, etc.) My line of code for this section is

```
<operation>
        <search position="before">
    <![CDATA[<input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]"]]>
  </search>
        <add>
    <![CDATA[
    <?php if(isset($option_value['option_image'])){?>
      <img src="<?php echo $option_value['option_image'];?>" border="0" alt="0" class="option-value-image optionimageimg" rel="<?php echo $option_value['option_image_thumb']."|||".$option_value['option_image_popup'];?>" />
    <?php } ?>
    ]]>
  </add>
    </operation>
```

The problem I am facing is adding a class

```
.optionimageimg.active {
```

border-color: #ffbcbc;

}

to the image once the image has been clicked on. The closet I have came to a solution is

```
$(this).closest('.option.form-group').find('.optionimage img').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

However, this doesn't do what I want. It will successfully add the border to a product image once clicked on but will then remove the border if you hover over a different product image.

What I want is for the border to actually remain on the clicked image until another image is clicked and not hovered over. If that make sense.

Example:

Image A    Unselected, border only on hover
Image B    Selected, border stays until different image is clicked
Image C    Unselected, border only on hover

Here's a link to one of my product pages if you need to see how it currently works (the circle options up under the color section)

http://www.classyrose.com/dresses.html?product_id=32

Thank you,

This is the full code to where my javascript code is found

```
function changeImage(image_thumb,image_popup){


  $('.zoomWindow').css('background-image','url("'+image_popup+'")');
  $('.product-info .image a').prop('href',image_popup);
  $('#image').prop('src',image_thumb);



}




if(change_option_image_hover){

    $('.option-value-image').hover(function(){

    var option_image = $(this).attr('rel');

    var image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
    var image_popup = option_image_popup;

    if(option_image){
      var option_image_split = option_image.split("|||");

      var option_image_thumb = option_image_split[0];
      var option_image_popup = option_image_split[1];

      if(option_image_thumb != "" && option_image_popup != ""){
        image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
        image_popup = option_image_popup;
      }
    }





    $(this).closest('.option.form-group').find('.optionimage img').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });




    $('.option-image-select > option').hover(function(){

    var option_image = $(this).attr('rel');

    var image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
    var image_popup = option_image_popup;

    if(option_image){
      var option_image_split = option_image.split("|||");

      var option_image_thumb = option_image_split[0];
      var option_image_popup = option_image_split[1];

      if(option_image_thumb != "" && option_image_popup != ""){
        image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
        image_popup = option_image_popup;
      }
    }

    changeImage(image_thumb,image_popup);
  });





    $('.option input').hover(function(){

    var option_image = $(this).attr('rel');

    var image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
    var image_popup = option_image_popup;

    if(option_image){
      var option_image_split = option_image.split("|||");

      var option_image_thumb = option_image_split[0];
      var option_image_popup = option_image_split[1];

      if(option_image_thumb != "" && option_image_popup != ""){
        image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
        image_popup = option_image_popup;
      }
    }

    changeImage(image_thumb,image_popup);

  });




    $('.option label').hover(function(){

    var option_image = $(this).attr('rel');
    var image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
    var image_popup = option_image_popup;

    if(option_image){
      var option_image_split = option_image.split("|||");

      var option_image_thumb = option_image_split[0];
      var option_image_popup = option_image_split[1];

      if(option_image_thumb != "" && option_image_popup != ""){
        image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
        image_popup = option_image_popup;
      }
    }

    changeImage(image_thumb,image_popup);
  });








}












if(change_option_image_select){
$(".option").keyup(function() {
  $(".option-image-select option:selected" ).each(function() {
    var option_image = $(this).attr('rel');

    var image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
    var image_popup = option_image_popup;

    if(option_image){
      var option_image_split = option_image.split("|||");

      var option_image_thumb = option_image_split[0];
      var option_image_popup = option_image_split[1];

      if(option_image_thumb != "" && option_image_popup != ""){
        image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
        image_popup = option_image_popup;
      }
    }

    changeImage(image_thumb,image_popup);
  });
});


$(".option select").keyup(function() {
  $(".option-image-select option:selected" ).each(function() {
    var option_image = $(this).attr('rel');

    var image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
    var image_popup = option_image_popup;

    if(option_image){
      var option_image_split = option_image.split("|||");

      var option_image_thumb = option_image_split[0];
      var option_image_popup = option_image_split[1];

      if(option_image_thumb != "" && option_image_popup != ""){
        image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
        image_popup = option_image_popup;
      }
    }

    changeImage(image_thumb,image_popup);
  });
});




$(".option select").click(function() {
  $(".option-image-select option:selected" ).each(function() {
    var option_image = $(this).attr('rel');

    var image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
    var image_popup = option_image_popup;

    if(option_image){
      var option_image_split = option_image.split("|||");

      var option_image_thumb = option_image_split[0];
      var option_image_popup = option_image_split[1];

      if(option_image_thumb != "" && option_image_popup != ""){
        image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
        image_popup = option_image_popup;
      }
    }

    changeImage(image_thumb,image_popup);
  });
});







    $('.options input').click(function(){

    var option_image = $(this).attr('rel');
    var image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
    var image_popup = option_image_popup;


    if(option_image){
      var option_image_split = option_image.split("|||");

      var option_image_thumb = option_image_split[0];
      var option_image_popup = option_image_split[1];

      if(option_image_thumb != "" && option_image_popup != ""){
        image_thumb = option_image_thumb;
        image_popup = option_image_popup;
      }
    }

    changeImage(image_thumb,image_popup);

  });



}
```

Here's my php

```
<operation>
            <search position="before">
        <![CDATA[<input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]"]]>
      </search>
            <add>
        <![CDATA[
        <?php if(isset($option_value['option_image'])){?>
          <img src="<?php echo $option_value['option_image'];?>" border="0" alt="0" class="option-value-image optionimageimg" rel="<?php echo $option_value['option_image_thumb']."|||".$option_value['option_image_popup'];?>" />
        <?php } ?>
        ]]>
      </add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="replace">
        <![CDATA[<input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]"]]>
      </search>
            <add>
         <![CDATA[<input type="radio" rel="<?php echo $option_value['option_image_thumb']."|||".$option_value['option_image_popup'];?>" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]"]]>
      </add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="replace">
        <![CDATA[<label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>]]>
      </search>
            <add>
        <![CDATA[<label rel="<?php echo $option_value['option_image_thumb']."|||".$option_value['option_image_popup'];?>" for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>]]>
      </add>
        </operation>
```

Comment: How are you adding the `click` handler? Is it something like `$("img").click(...`?

Comment: Do you want the border to stay on the image even when another image is being hovered over?

Comment: I'm new to Jquery and don't know all the handlers. I have read about the click handler, just didn't know how I should incorporate it into my code

Comment: Yes! Once another image is clicked that's when the border should be removed and added to the new clicked image.

Comment: Is the image that is being hovered over supposed to have a border until it is no longer being hovered over?

Comment: Yes! That is correct

Comment: Ok. I'll try to get you a solution; however, it may take a little while because I have some other things I need to do... Sorry. :(

Comment: I've been working on this for weeks, lol waiting a little while longer want be a problem at all, and thank you!

Comment: Before I give my answer, I'd need to know when your block of jQuery runs. What 'set's it off'?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm actually not sure.

Comment: Did you make this website?

Comment: I created it in Opencart and purchased a theme, And have major changes to the theme to personalize it for myself.

Comment: Could you give me the context of the jquery above?

Comment: Attach the full code here?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm getting there.

Comment: I added my jquery code and php code to the original post if you need it

Comment: Thanks. You're a champ. :D

Comment: Wow, though, that's a lot of unnecessary whitespace... (I know; you didn't come here for code review. Sorry ... sorta.)

Comment: Omg I know lol, I usually minify everything once I have completed whatever i'm doing. Everything bunched up hurts my eyes.

Comment: I'm going to post my answer. However, you'll have to remember that I might have missed something. You may have to be patient. :D

Comment: Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: I messed up the filename for change 3... I've corrected it now.

Comment: Sorry, but you really shouldn't publish a website that has alot of issues, especially if it concerns monetary transactions

Comment: The issues aren't within the scope of this question. I can start a chat room if the OP wants

Comment: @CarlMarkham: She doesn't have enough rep to **use** a chatroom.

Comment: AFAIK you can join chatrooms regardless or rep, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118717/classyrose

Comment: @CarlMarkham "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."

Comment: @CarlMarkham also, I created this website in opencart. I have been working on this site for months trying to fix all issues. I have hired people from elance/upwork and fiverr. Although the site is published, I haven't done any advertising to attract customers or have received any payments. I'm really trying to get it customer ready and will not plan on doing anything to attract any customers until I have done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes you need to make. (Not promising everything will work on the first try; I may have missed something.)

---

***Change 1:***

In *option_image.css*,

change

```
.optionimageimg.active {
```

to

```
.optionimageimg.active,
.optionimageimg:hover {
```

---

***Change 2:***

In *option_image.js*,

*remove* or *comment out*

```
$(this).closest('.option.form-group').find('.optionimage img').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

---

***Change 3:***

In *option_image.js*,

add this code

```
$(".optionimageimg").click(
    function () {
        //remove border from the one that currently has it
        $(".optionimageimg.active").removeClass("active");

        //add the border to this image
        $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    );
```

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, would the person who downvoted care to explain why this is a low quality answer?

Comment: @ShakilaReed-Southerland: Glad for you! (victory dance!) Please accept the answer. ;)

Comment: @ShakilaReed-Southerland: Your welcome. Have a party!